# an absolute positioned view inside a TouchableOpacity does not show in React Native

Tags: react-native

When I wrap a view inside a TouchableOpacity as follows, it does not show anymore.

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onLongPress={() => {
      console.log("LONG PRESS ....");
   }}
>
          <View
            style={{
              ...styles.event,
              left: left,
              top: top,
              height: height,
              width: width,
              borderRadius: 5,
              backgroundColor: chooseColor(event.activityType, event.calendar),
              opacity: event.calendar == 0 ? 1.0 : 0.5
            }}
          />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Remove the View and add style of View to TouchableOpacity. i mean pass style prop in TouchableOpacity rather in View.

Comment: Still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap View with TouchableOpacity. Do it reverse.